# Angularjs Dropdown appearing white space in first option in Internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack

```
<select id="selectIdentity" name="selectIdentity" required ng-trim="true" ng-change="changedValue(addUser.identityProvider)" ng-model="addUser.identityProvider" >
       <option value="" selected hidden />
        <option ng-repeat="idprovider in identityProvider" value="{{idprovider .UOM}}">
            {{idprovider}}
        </option>                       
        </select>
```

for all the browsers white space is not appearing in first option of the dropdown but in IE11 shows White space. how to remove that white space in IE.

here i have created a fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/gkJve/1502/

kindly check it in IE browser

Can any one tell me how to fix this

Comment: most likely a css problem

Comment: Hi madalin ivascu, i have created a fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/gkJve/1502/ kindly check it in IE and other browsers

Comment: @Vinoth Can you please stop rejecting my edits (second attempt https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16574778 ), the angular tag is just wrong, this question only targets angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem sees to be with the hidden attribute of your empty option